# 2-dimensional array to object (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

I have an array, that holds a large number of two-dimensional arrays:

```
var myArray = [
    [2260146,2334221,"copy"],
    [1226218,2334231,"copy"],
    [2230932,-1,"copy"],
    [2230933,-1,"copy"],
    [2230934,-1,"copy"]
]
```

I need to convert this array into an object of the following form to send it as JSON:

```
var json = [
  {
    "s_id": 2260146,
    "t_id": 2334221,
    "type": "copy"
  },
  {
    "s_id": 1226218,
    "t_id": 2334231,
    "type": "copy"
  },
  {
    "s_id": 12,
    "t_id": -1,
    "type": "copy"
  }
]
```

("s_id" should be `myArray[0][0]`, "t_id `myArray[0][1]`, and "type" `myArray[0][2]` and so on.)

How can I get the array in the desired form? Thanks in advance.

Comment: what have you tried? I'd say just iterate over the array and make the array of objects by hand.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
json = myArray.map(function(x) {
    return {    
        "s_id": x[0],
        "t_id": x[1],
        "type": x[2]
    }
})
```

Be aware that [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) is not supported in IEs < 9.

Comment: So in order to support IE < 9 I would have to do something like hsz suggested below?

Comment: @maze: yes, if you use jquery anyways, `$.map` is a better choice.

Answer (score 4):

You could [destructure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) the parameter in `map` and use [Shorthand property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#New_notations_in_ECMAScript_2015):

```js
const myArray=[[2260146,2334221,"copy"],[1226218,2334231,"copy"],[2230932,-1,"copy"],[2230933,-1,"copy"],[2230934,-1,"copy"]]

const output = myArray.map(([s_id, t_id, type]) => ({ s_id, t_id, type }))

console.log(output)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try with:

```
var length = myArray.length,
    json   = [];

for ( var i = 0; i < length; i++ ) {
  var subArray = myArray[i],
      item = {
        s_id: subArray[0],
        t_id: subArray[1],
        type: subArray[2]
      };
   json.push(item);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How to traverse through the following structure from 2D array

weekearn,monthearn is variable containing array of objects.
I need loop because I don't know the number of products

```
          const stackdata = {          
    
                       datasets:[{
                         data: weekearn,
                         label: 'Product 1',
                         backgroundColor: 'rgb(255, 87, 51)',
                         borderColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',            
                     },
                     {
                         data: monthearn,
                         label: 'Product 2',
                         backgroundColor: 'rgb(155, 87, 51)',
                         borderColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 32)',
                        
                     }
                 ]
             };
```