# How to convert a 2D Javascript array to object with identifiers

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, javascript-objects

What's the best way to convert a 2D array into an object with identifiers that count up?

There could be an unlimited number of identifiers in the object - based on what's in the array.

So in the array we might have

```
data: [
    ["Lisa", "Heinz"],
    ["Bob", "Sleigh"]
  ]
```

And we'd be keen that the array looked something like this in the end:

```
data: {
    person1 {
{name: Lisa}, 
{last_name: Heinz}
},
person2 {
{name: Bob},
{last_name: Sleigh}
}
}
```

[Using map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14397927/2-dimensional-array-to-object-javascript) I can create an array of objects, but this isn't quite

```
json = formData.map(function(x) {
    return {    
        "name": x[0],
        "last_name": x[1]
    }
})
console.log(json);
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [2-dimensional array to object (JavaScript)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14397927/2-dimensional-array-to-object-javascript)

Comment: Not quite. The code example I currently have is based off this @pilchard - but it returns an array of objects - as I currently have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this? I changed your object structure a bit to be easier to access.

```js
let newDataObj = {}
for (let person of data) {
    const identifier = `person${data.indexOf(person)}`;
    const [name, last_name] = person;
    newDataObj[identifier] = { name, last_name };
}
```